# Firebase updateChildValues works in IOS but not in Web and Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, firebase, angularfire

Firebase Update child which is updateChildValues in iOS updates by not deleting the old values but in Web and Android it removes the old data and adds. Looks like a bug in the firebase side not sure.

iOS Code

```
 self.viewFirebase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@messages/%@",fOrgURL,self.userHash]];
 Firebase *insertData = [self.viewFirebase childByAutoId];
 Firebase *notificationRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@notifications/%@/%@/",fOrgURL,fromHash,self.userHash]];
  NSDictionary *dummyData = @{@"a":@"0"};
  NSDictionary *messageIDDict = @{insertData.key : dummyData};

    Firebase *lastData = [notificationRef childByAppendingPath:@"inbox/"];

   NSDictionary *lastSentData = @{@"msgs":messageIDDict,@"sender": toHash,@"lastSender":[[AuthDataStore sharedAuth] pushKey], @"text" : messageInput, @"ack":@"ok", @"time":[NSNumber numberWithInt:timeStamp]};
   [lastData updateChildValues:lastSentData];
```

Android Code

```
 //Note: receiverinbox and notificationMsgs are hashmaps;
 Firebase mNotificationref=new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+"/notifications");
 receiverinbox.put("sender",userid);
 receiverinbox.put("text", input));
 receiverinbox.put("time", Utilities.getCurrentTime());
 receiverinbox.put("ack","no");
 notificationMsgs.put(messagepush,placeholder); // messagepush is firebase pushid, placeholder is not null
 receiverinbox.put("msgs",notificationMsgs);

 mNotificationref.child(chatwithid).child(userhash).child("inbox").updateChildren(receiverinbox);
```

Angular JS

```
 var msgsVal = {};
 msgsval[msgId] = {placeholder : 1}; // MsgID is firebase pushkey
 var rcvrNotificationConvRef = new Firebase(sessionURL + '/notifications/' + $scope.ustoId + '/' + msgkey);
 rcvrNotificationConvRef.child('inbox').update({
 sender: sender,
 time: time,
 text: msgintext,
 ack: 'No',
 lastSender: $scope.usLoggedUserId,
 msgs : msgsVal
 });
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you're running on all three platforms? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Have added the code. Let me know if that suffice.

Comment: I quickly wrote up this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mngm289m/. You'll see that the node is initially empty (it logs `null` in the output), then it gets the three values from calling `ref.set` and then finally two of those values are overwritten with `ref.update`. If you are seeing different behavior, can you modify the fiddle to reproduce what you have?

Comment: Have updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mngm289m/1/

Comment: Right, now I see it. You're passing nested children into `update`, which will only patch on the top-level and essentially call `set` on each property in the update (see the documentation for a better explanation than I could possibly write up: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html). If you want to also apply the update/patch logic to descendants, you can write your application code to handle that. So first update the top-level: `ref.update({ time: Date.now() });` and then update the child: `ref.child('skills').update({ "back-end": { "js": "firebase" } });`

Comment: Yeah but it works fine for iOS it doesn't set it updates. Hard to do the same thing in android and web?

Comment: The docs I linked to are very explicit about the behavior for JavaScript. What you're seeing is the documented behavior there and I just provided you a way to get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to know was it hard to not implement it and why just iOS supported it. No problem. The thing was we didn't wanted it to take 2 calls rite now we have fixed the problem but didn't want to take two calls to do it.

Comment: If you want a single call, you can use a transaction. It will give you all the current data, that you can then modify and have it written to your Firebase.

Comment: The API is supposed to be consistent across all platforms and should work the way the JavaScript documentation I linked above described. Can you reproduce the deeper level patching on iOS in an minimal standalone Xcode project? If so, please send it to me on support@firebase.com.

Answer (score 0):

In Android we can use `push()` method to append data to a list in multiuser applications. The [push() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) generates a unique key every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference.